# How to get cookie in magento 2 admin controller?

Tags: cookies, magento2

I create a grid listing to report data. I have created to field From date and to date for admin select to filter data. So I set cookies from_date and to_date. When I show grid it load two time, the first time it can get cookie value but the second time it can't get cookie value. Show the grid can't display right value.
I also create a controller in Controller/Adminhtml/Report/MyController.php to export data to CSV. It work fine. But I can't get from_date and to_date from cookie to set it in my collection query.

My code as below:

```
public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);

        $this->request = $request;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;

        $from = $this->cookieManager->getCookie('from_date');
        $to = $this->cookieManager->getCookie('to_date');
        $from_date = $this->request->getParam('from_date');
        $to_date = $this->request->getParam('to_date');
}
```

How to get cookie in magento 2 admin controller?

Thanks & Best regards,
BienHV

Comment: check this link --- https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-crete-update-delete-cookie-in-magento-2.html

Comment: Hi @MohitPatel I find the error by when I refresh the report page. I check network tab. It call to ajax url to load the grid listing. This ajax reset cookie thus the cookie not existing. Could you help me how to reset cookie when magento ui_component call ajax? OR How to turn off ajax in ui_component listing? Thank you so much!